# How to stop extrarowheight from affecting first row

Tags: tables, formatting, memoir

I have used `extrarowheight` to add some additional space between rows in a table containing text only. While this works fine, it also affects the first row. Is there a way to stop this, or maybe remove the additional spacing in the first row only? I realise I could achieve the space between the rows differently, but I want to avoid that if possible. The blue arrow denotes the space I would like reduced.

Here a screenshot and MWE.

[image: Example Table]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\settypeblocksize{237mm}{150mm}{*} % size of text block on page

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\caption{Severity of identified problems and proposed changes}
\label{some_changes}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{5mm} %add row padding
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}p{3.5cm} >{\raggedright}p{8.5cm} p{1.5cm}}
\toprule
Change & Justification & Severity\\
\midrule
1. \parbox[t]{3cm}{\raggedright A few meaningful definitions} &
Just some sample text that is longer than a couple of lines. This text has 
no meaning, it's just a sample text and does not do anything but fill some 
space here. & 
High\\
2. \parbox[t]{3cm}{\raggedright Some other thing that needs a change} &
Just some sample text that is longer than a couple of lines. This text has 
no meaning, it's just a sample text and does not do anything but fill some 
space here. & 
Medium\\
3. \parbox[t]{3cm}{\raggedright Some other thing that needs a change} &
Just some sample text that is longer than a couple of lines. This text has 
no meaning, it's just a sample text and does not do anything but fill some 
space here. &  
Low\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: off-the-wall suggestion, not tested.  `\smash` the entries in the first row so that they have no height or depth.  (not in a position to test, and admittedly this is rather farfetched, if not downright weird.)

Comment: Thanks, @barbarabeeton. I tried it, by putting all entries in the first row in smash ... \smash{changes} etc. That had an effect! It made the row height much larger :D But thanks for the weird suggestion :)

Comment: well, now we know that it's *not* a useful approach.  thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**An alternative solution:**

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\settypeblocksize{237mm}{150mm}{*} % size of text block on page

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htb]
\caption{Severity of identified problems and proposed changes}
\label{some_changes}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{5mm} %add row padding
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}p{3.5cm} >{\raggedright}p{8.5cm} p{1.5cm}}
\toprule
\\[-3\normalbaselineskip] % <------------- Add this
Change & Justification & Severity\\
\midrule
1. \parbox[t]{3cm}{\raggedright A few meaningful definitions} &
Just some sample text that is longer than a couple of lines. This text has 
no meaning, it's just a sample text and does not do anything but fill some 
space here. & 
High\\
2. \parbox[t]{3cm}{\raggedright Some other thing that needs a change} &
Just some sample text that is longer than a couple of lines. This text has 
no meaning, it's just a sample text and does not do anything but fill some 
space here. & 
Medium\\
3. \parbox[t]{3cm}{\raggedright Some other thing that needs a change} &
Just some sample text that is longer than a couple of lines. This text has 
no meaning, it's just a sample text and does not do anything but fill some 
space here. &  
Low\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The main idea is to add a negative spacing after the `\toprule` to negate the padding added from the `\extrarowheight`. Adding

```
\\[-3\normalbaselineskip]
```

seems to restore the first row to its original height (without padding). But of course, you can always change the value in the square brackets to whatever you like.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Zarko and @Troy. Both solutions work of course, but I chose Troy's answer as it is what I had wanted, and because I had tried the addlinespace-solution before myself. Thanks very much to both you. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 4):

is use `\addlinespace[5mm]` from package `booktabs` acceptable option to you?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\settypeblocksize{237mm}{150mm}{*} % size of text block on page

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\caption{Severity of identified problems and proposed changes}
\label{some_changes}
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}p{0.6cm}@{\ }>{\raggedright}p{3cm} >{\raggedright}p{8.5cm} p{1.5cm}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Change} & Justification & Severity\\
\midrule\addlinespace[5mm]
1. & A few meaningful definitions &
\lipsum*[11] &
High\\  \addlinespace[5mm]
2. & \raggedright Some other thing that needs a change &
\lipsum*[11] &
Medium\\ \addlinespace[5mm]
3. &  Some other thing that needs a change &
\lipsum*[11] &
Low\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Zarko - special thanks also for showing me an alternative way to deal with my columns, so I don't have to use parbox anymore.  Your way is better :)